# Estimating operator norm with random variables

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, matrix-norms

Suppose $1\leq p<\infty$ and $1\leq q<\infty$. Write $\|x\|_p:=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^p)^{1/p}$ for the $L^p$-norm of $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and similarly define $\|x\|_q$. We write $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_p)$ to mean that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is regarded as a (real) normed vector space equipped with the $L^p$-norm. Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with real entries, and regard $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ as a linear operator from $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_p)$ to $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_q)$.

Write $\mathbb{D}^n_p:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|_p\leq 1\}$. Recall that the operator norm of $A$ is
$$\|A\|_{\text{op}}:=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{D}_p^n}\|Ax\|_q.$$
Note that because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, all norms on it are equivalent. Thus, one can deduce that $\|A\|_{\text{op}}<\infty$. The value of $\|A\|_{\text{op}}$ is difficult to calculate for large values of $n$ (even for $n=3$; for example, see [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877202/why-is-the-operator-norm-so-hard-to-calculate)). Thus, I was trying to formulate a probabilistic way to approximate $\|A\|_{\text{op}}$ as follows. We let $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $x_1$ having a uniform distribution on $\mathbb{D}_p^n$. My question is then:

> 1. For $j\geq 1$, define the random variables $X_j:=\max_{1\leq k\leq j}\|Ax_k\|_q$. Is it true that $X_j$ converges in probability to $\|A\|_{\text{op}}?$ In other words, is it true that for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $\lim_{j\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\Big|\|A\|_{\text{op}}-X_j\Big|>\epsilon)=0$? (If the general case for arbitrary $p,q\in[1,\infty)$ is too complicated, do we know that the result holds for any $p,q\in[1,\infty)$?)
> 2. If the answer to the first question is yes, then what can we say about the rate of convergence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It turns out that the almost sure convergence holds (actually, if an non-decreasing sequence of random variables converges in probability, it converges also almost surely). To see this, observe that $X_j\to X_\infty=:\sup_{k\geqslant 1}\lVert Ax_k\rVert_q$ almost surely. Moreover, for almost every $\omega$, the sequence $\left(x_k(\omega)\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ is dense in $\mathbb D_p^n$. Therefore $X_j\to \sup_{k\geqslant 1}\lVert Ax_k\rVert_q=\sup_{x\in\mathbb D_p^n}\lVert Ax\rVert_q=\lVert A\rVert_{\mathrm{op}}$.
2. Since $X_j\leqslant \lVert A\rVert_{\mathrm{op}} $, we have
   $$
   \mathbb{P}\left(\Big|\|A\|_{\text{op}}-X_j\Big|>\epsilon\right)=\mathbb{P} 
   \left( \|A\|_{\text{op}}-\epsilon >X_j\right)=\mathbb{P} 
   \left( \|A\|_{\text{op}}-\epsilon > \max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant j}\|Ax_k\|_q\right)
   $$
   and using the fact that the random variables $\left(\|Ax_k\|_q\right)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant j}$ are independent and identically distributed, we derive that
   $$
   \mathbb{P}\left(\Big|\|A\|_{\text{op}}-X_j\Big|>\epsilon\right)=\mathbb P\left(\|Ax_1\|_q<\|A\|_{\text{op}}-\epsilon\right)^j.
   $$
   When $A=I$, the involved probability can be explicitely computed but for the general case I do not know.

Comment: Thank you, and does the claim "$(x_k(\omega))_{k\geq 1}$ is dense..." hold in general when $x_1$ has a uniform distribution on a "nicely behaved" set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (let's say an open connected set with piecewise smooth boundary)?

Comment: I am not sure how nicely behaved the set $S$ it should be, however, you need that $\lambda_n(S\setminus B(x,r))<\lambda_n(S)$ for each $x\in S$ to get density (as the probability that a point with rational coordinates cannot be approximated by elements of $(x_k)$ would be $0$).